# Как получить не список значений, а значение в фильтрации параметров запроса

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

В модели отношение многим к многим

**serializer.py**

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
```

Фильтрация происходит следующим образом:

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('level', queryset=Level.objects.filter(id=level)))
```

При таком запросе http://...//?level=1, имею:

```
{
    ...
    "level": [
        1
    ]
    ...
}
```

Хочу получить:

```
{
    ...
    "level": 1
    ...
}
```

Comment: values(*fields)¶
Возвращает ValuesQuerySet — подкласс QuerySet, который возвращает словари с результатом вместо объектов моделей.  https://djbook.ru/rel1.4/ref/models/querysets.html  это не подойдёт ?

Comment: @Интик, Получить словарь и по ключу распаковать список?